# Cannot view records in form ms access after assigning record-source

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2007

Please help,

I have this table ‘Source_RM’:

**Source**.........**Raw Material**.....**Waste Date**.....**Waste Quantity**

Store.............Sugar...........13/06/2013.................10

Store.............Salt...............12/06/2013.................13

Production....Sugar............17/06/2013.................10

Vendor..........Sugar............15/06/2013.................10

I have a main form where the client can perform queries passed on controls (text box, combo box ..)

In the main form I need to display a query result passed on combo box value:

The result wanted: the client choose the source from a combo box "cmbSource"  so the result will be a table contain the source and total waste i.e.:

**Source**...**Total**

Store.......23

What I did is:

1. Created a form (“Blank Form”) name it: frmResult
2. In the main form I added Subform, In subform wizard in use an existing form I chose ‘frmResult’
3. After I choose the source from ‘cmbSource ‘ and click the button’ cmdFilter’
4. I wrote this code in VBA :

> Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()
>
> Me.FormTemp.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT Source_ID, SUM(Quantity) AS       Total FROM Source_RM WHERE Source =  ' " & Me. cmbSource.Value & " '   GROUP BY Source_ID;"
>
> End Sub

After I click the button, the FormTemp has the RecordSource (I know from the record number at the bottom bar’ 1 of 1’) but the FormTemp still blank .. I need to show the result of query in FormTemp

Note : Date entry in FormTemp is set to NO.
I put the default view of FormTemp to Datasheet.

Please any Ideas

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to add `Me.FormTemp.Form.Refresh` after the recordsource is set?

Comment: I tried recreating this, but I got nothing.  As a last resort you could always use a recordsource set to the SELECT statement and then loop through the records with a running total.